# Can you automate the App UDID when running a test from the command line?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, instruments

I run a command line test that runs Instruments on the iPhone Simulator. Unfortunately, every time I do a Build the UDID changes which means I have to update my script. E.g. see this error message:

```
Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid: /Path/To/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9B0DF4D4-941C-4B65-84E0-ETC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8EE5CBCA-3107-48B5-8A54-ETC/myApp.app
```

Is there any way to avoid copying/pasting this UDID all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a bash script that reads the most recent UDID from the folder where they are being generated, stores that to a variable and calls instruments using that variable. It would look something like

```
cd parentFolderOfUDIDs
mostRecentUDID = "$(\ls -1dt */ | head -n 1)"
instruments /path/to/app/$mostRecentUDID/myApp.app
```